# #import "Project-Swift.h" File does not refresh

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I have a project with Swift and Objective-C code. In my current project I have the problem that the `#import "Project-Swift.h"` file does not refresh if I add new Swift modules.

```
#import "Project-Swift.h" // does not refresh if I add .swift files
```

So in the Objective-C universe, the swift code is not available. the files exists, but does only contains default `#defines` etc. No project related stuff.

Clear Cache, rebuild, delete Derived Data does not help.

Comment: try restarting xcode

Comment: Solved it. @objc(...) is mandatory now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it. Forgot `@objc(<class>)`. It is mandatory.

Details here (Migrating)

[Migrating Objective-C Code to Swift](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/PRERELEASE/IOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html)

And here (Swift Type Compatibility)

[Interacting with Objective-C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_34)

Answer (score 2):

In my case it worked by building for the other target I had on my project:

- Check you have prefixed your class with `@objc`
- Choose the other scheme (target)
  [image]
- Build || Run
- The bridging file updates
- Change the scheme back to the target I was working on

Answer (score 1):

Just use @objc before Swift Class that you want to use in Object-C code then Build the project. 
For example:

```
 @objc class Person : NSObject
 {
  // Swfit code goes here.
 }
```

Now #import "Project-Swift.h" will be available in you project to use.